# Подключение к локальному IP извне через php и js

Tags: php, xml, запрос, soap, vpn

В наличии:
1. Данные для подключения к внешнему серверу (IP, login, pass)
2. Проброшенный VPN-туннель с внешнего сервера на другой
3. Внутренний IP с набором сервисов для запроса (SOAP) (ip 192.168....)

Задача:
Отправить SOAP-запрос на внутренний IP и получить ответ.

Как организовать SOAP-запрос и получить xml-ответ, я понимаю. Вопрос в следующем - как подключиться к внутреннему IP?

Например, здесь я отправляю XMLHttpRequest() на переменную url. Но этот url прямой, к нему есть доступ из инета. А вот как через туннель - непонятно.

```
var url = "http://domain.com/MCAExportService/.....asmx";

function getKBM(client_iin) {
...
}

var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.open("POST", url, true);
...
    xmlHTTP.send(xml_request);
```

Comment: Вам это надо реализовать без перезагрузки страницы? И хотя бы IP-адрес у Вас должен быть

Comment: Привет. На данный момент застрял на моменте: скрипт сделал на cURL, загнал его на внешний сервер (78.40.....), через VNC-терминал этот скрипт отправляет запрос через туннель на внутренний сервер (192.168....), и получает ответ. Но через браузер это сделать не могу.

Comment: На каком именно моменте?

Comment: Напишите обработчик на РНР. Отправляйте запросы аккуратно через jQuery (`$.post()`) на обработчик. А вот на внутренний сервер - может не работать из-за портов.

Comment: Немного поподробней, если не сложно.

Comment: напишите мне на почу romanko95.rk@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Подключились извне, с разрешениями поборолись. `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: Ну хорошо что нашли всё таки способ)

Answer (score 0):

Подключиться к 'внутреннему' IP Вы сможете только имея доступ к 'внешнему'.
Внутренний IP - это адрес самого ПК внутри сети(рабочей, к примеру).
А внешний - это IP для доступа с других пк в интернете. И если доступ извне закрыт сисадмином - то просите 'ІР' под себя.